# Mac shell script to delete files

Tags: macos, shell

I have a Mac shell script to delete .rtf files. Now I want to delete folders names have only numbers (e.g. 1,2,3,10) and it should be older than 5 days. How can I write it?

My current script:

```
find "/Library/Agents/_wrk" -type f -name "*.rtf" -delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /path/to/files/ -type d -mtime +5 -name '*[0-9]*' -execdir rm -rf -- '{}' \;
```

Explanation:

- `-type d` we want directories,
- `-mtime +5` older than 5 days
- `-name` containing any digit in name
- `-execdir rm -rf` and we wanna delete it

**BE CAREFUL** - if you ran this line in wrong location in can destroy your system. `rm -rf` will delete all matched files without confirmation.
I suggest you to first run:

```
find /path/to/files/ -type d -mtime +5 -name '*[0-9]*'
```

to check if proper files are selected (it will only print matched files).

**EDIT:**
Above solution works, but generates errors (as stated in comment). It's because find tries to search in directories that were just deleted.

Lets assume we have this file structure (only dirs):

```
baseDir
   - digit1
      - digit2
   - nodigit
      - digit4
```

If you want to remove `digit1` and also `digit4` you should use command above. `find` will pass `digit1` to `rm` and directory will be deleted but `find` will try to traverse it anyway (generating error). But thanks to that it will also traverse not matched `nodigit` (and remoe `digit4`).

If you would like to remove only `digit1` directory and not traverse `nodigit` you can use this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*[0-9]*' -execdir rm -rf  -- '{}' \;
```

Using `-maxdepth` tells `find` if it should go into directories (and how deep). It also stops error from generating (because it doesn't tries to access them).

I'll just mention another solution: forwarding `stderr` from console so errors won't be printed.

Comment: can't we add the path for that

Comment: @AMNKumari I edited my answer to show path. But my warning is standing - `rm -rf` is dangerous and you should be careful.

Comment: thank you very much its working. if you know pls explain how to  set this as a schedule without run manually.

Comment: That is another question but you can Google `cron` (or look on Stack Overflow). It will allow you to run commands or scripts in schedule.

Comment: after i added this i got this error   find "/Library/Agents/_wrk/" -type d -mtime +5find . -type d -mtime +5 -name '*[0-9]*'

Comment: Yeah, I messed up something while copying from my machine. Should be fixed.

Comment: another small issue. my deleting folders have some content files. (ex. file.zip,test.txt) so i added like this find /Library/Agents/_wrk/ -type d -mtime +5 -name '*[0-9]*' -execdir rm -rf -- '{}' \;

Comment: its deleting my folders but it shows an error find: /Library/Agents/_wrk//1:Nos such file or directory (1)  after deleting folder 1 its searching again.

Comment: I to updated with `-rf`. Interesting that I was able to describe risks, but forgot to put it into command :)

Comment: its deleting my folders but it shows an error find: /Library/Agents/_wrk//1:Nos such file or directory (1)  after deleting folder 1 its searching again.

Comment: @AMNKumari No, it works diffrently - as I explained in EDIT. Have a look :)